# Unable to Group dataframe by Month number

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have the following code but it seems the line

```
cs.groupby(cs['Disbursal_Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['Revenue'].sum()
```

just returns the entire dataframe without the data grouping by Month number.

Any help is much appreciated

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import numpy as np

os.chdir("C:/csv/")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

cs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])

cs.drop(cs.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)

cs = cs[cs["Booked"] == 1]

cs['Disbursal_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(cs['Disbursal_Date'])

cs.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

cs['Revenue'] = np.where(cs['Loan_Amount'] < 1000, 28,
              np.where((cs['Loan_Amount'] > 1000) & (cs['APR'] < 0.3), 0.0525 * cs['Loan_Amount'],
              np.where((cs['Loan_Amount'] > 1000) & (cs['APR'] > 0.3), 0.0275 * cs['Loan_Amount'], 0)))


cs.loc[cs.Revenue >= 175, "Revenue"] = 175
cs.loc[cs.Revenue <= 52.50, "Revenue"] = 52.50

cs.groupby(cs['Disbursal_Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['Revenue'].sum()

print(cs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning the result from your `cs.groupby`. Something like:

```py
cs = cs.groupby(cs['Disbursal_Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['Revenue'].sum()
print(cs)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. When this prints, it only shows the 'Revenue' and not the months the revenue belongs to. How would I return this? Many thanks

Comment: Try this: `cs  = cs.groupby(cs['Disbursal_Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['Revenue'].sum().to_frame('Revenue').reset_index()
print(cs)`